# Screen Scraping password protected sites

Tags: screen-scraping, import.io

I just have a very general question, but of vital importance to me. May I know if import.io supports screen scraping of password protected sites? If not, could someone suggest some tools that do?  Thanks in advance

Comment: This is not the place to ask this question. Stack overflow is generally for technical questions related to programming.

Comment: Here is the link on how to ask questions here http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks for the reply and yeah, when I sent an email regarding my question I didn't get a reply and hence asked out here and on facebook. Anyways, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

import.io does not support password protected websites currently